# WSO2 EI how to increasing Endpoint timeout?

Tags: wso2, ei

I have setted configure and endpoint timeout but it have below response.

What should I pay attention if I want to increase endpoint timeout?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
The server didn't respond in time.
    </body>
</html>
```

**There are 3 steps to set timeout but it appear fault....**

1) Global timeout defined in synapse.properties (EI_HOME\conf\synapse.properties)

synapse.global_timeout_interval=17000000

2) Socket timeout defined in the passthru-http.properties (EI_HOME\conf\passthru-http.properties )

http.socket.timeout=18000000

3) Also set timeout in API.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="ep_dsData" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.origin.ds}/api/v1/GetData">
        <timeout>
            <duration>17000000</duration>
            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
        </timeout>
    </http>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: Did you get this error from the client side? Do you want to increase timeout for all endpoints in EI or a specific one?

Comment: Yes, this error message is response to client side and I hope I can increase timeout for all endpoints.
Do you have any idea to solve this problem?Thank you.

Comment: You have configured the timeout value as 5 hours, what is the use case that needs this? provide some info the client system and also the backend server or services that are used

Comment: I use the external http backend services to get a big data but it take a lot of time to wait the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following link clearly explains the configurations requried for tuning the timeout variables in WSO2 EI. Please refer it once again.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/WSO2+Enterprise+Integrator+Best+Practices#WSO2EnterpriseIntegratorBestPractices-Workingwithendpoints

The timeout limit shared in the question is very abnormal, 5 hours.

Remember, the following..

1. http.socket.timeout > max(Global endpoint timeout,Timeout of individual endpoints).
2. Also if you have configured a timeout value at the endpoint level, the global timeout value is not taken into consideration for that endpoint. For all the other endpoints, which do not have a timeout value configured, the global value is considered as the timeout value.

Comment: I have changed 2 parameters of timeout in EI as below.If I set below parameter(synapse.global_timeout_interval and http.socket.timeout) less than < 60 seconds have normal timeout.On the other hand, below parameter(synapse.global_timeout_interval and http.socket.timeout)  > 60 seconds and it is strange that always will be not exceed more than 60 seconds timeout. Whether have other parameters need to be set or changed?Thank you. 
Parameter 1 : synapse.global_timeout_interval(<EI_HOME>/conf/synapse.properties) 
Parameter 2: http.socket.timeout(<EI_HOME>/conf/passthru-http.properties)

Comment: Since,  if you have configured a timeout value at the endpoint level, the global timeout value (synapse.global_timeout_interval) will not taken into consideration for that endpoint. Try changing the value at the endpoint level

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I have setted the timeout parameters that synapse.global_timeout_interval = 300000, http.socket.timeout = 600000 and the endpoint level (Connection Timeout of Action = never timeout)...it always will be not exceed more than 60 seconds timeout...If exceed more than 60 seconds, the client side will be response the error message:
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
The server didn't respond in time.
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Since the http socket timeout is specified as 60 seconds, the client side error makes sense and the connection socket will be terminated by wso2

Comment: But I have set the http.socket.timeout = 600000(10 minutes not 60 seconds)....and it's not exceed more than 60 seconds timeout...

Comment: I suppose WSO2 is fine. Check on backend http service that is used. Check the socket timeout on that system and also the Gateway system

Comment: I delete the EI file and reinstall, it can work....thank you for your help.